# Calling bpy.ops.object.bake_image() gives error "No valid images found to bake to"

Tags: python, scripting, texture-baking

I'm trying to write a script that'll automatically combine different textures each with a unique UV into a common UV.

This is a portion of my script so far:

```
# Create new image
bpy.ops.image.new(name=currentImageName, width=1024, height=1024)

# Set bake margins
bpy.context.scene.render.bake_margin = 2

# Set the UV coordinates
ob.data.uv_textures['SmartProject'].active = True

# Specify the bake type
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.bake_type = "TEXTURE"

#Bake the image
bpy.ops.object.bake_image()
```

When I call this last line, however, I get the error "No valid images found to bake to," in spite of the fact that I just created a new image. I can't find any way to specify which image I want Blender to bake to.

Thanks for your help

Comment: i think you need to set the image you created as active

Comment: I think so too, but it doesn't seem like there's any clear way to do that. bpy.data.image doesn't have an member functions which let you set an image as 'active.'

Comment: I've also seen people suggest I use ob.data.uv_textures['SmartProject'].data[0].image = bpy.data.images[currentImageName] to set the destination image, but then I get the error basically saying that uv_texture[' ... '].data has no elements, so I get an indexing error. -

Comment: Is this different to the previous question you asked? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54108/texture-baking-in-a-script-how-do-you-specify-the-destination-image

Comment: No, but that one didn't get any responses, I figure because I submitted it on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: You shouldn't post your question more than once. If you have more information then you can use the 'edit' button below the post.

Comment: Also, you need to '@' people for them to be notified of your comment, e.g. @RayMairlot

Answer (score 5):

There were a few apparent issues.

The first is that the I needed to use the function

```
ob.data.uv_textures['SmartProject'].data[0].image = bpy.data.images[currentImageName]
```

to select the correct image. This wasn't enough though, since if the object 'ob' was in edit mode, data would have no elements, returning an index error for data[0].

The next issue was that data has many elements, so I had to actually loop through them setting them all to the current image. The correct code block is now:

```
# Create new image
bpy.ops.image.new(name=currentImageName, width=1024, height=1024)

# Set bake margins
bpy.context.scene.render.bake_margin = 2

# Set the UV coordinates
ob.data.uv_textures['SmartProject'].active = True

# Specify the bake type
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.bake_type = "TEXTURE"

# Exit edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Set the target image
for d in ob.data.uv_textures['SmartProject'].data:
    d.image = bpy.data.images[currentImageName]

# Enter edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

#Bake the image
bpy.ops.object.bake_image()
```